# I cannot connect my flutter app with firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter

Can anyone fix this error? This occurred while I was trying to connect my flutter project with firebase an run the app.

Would really appreciate if anyone can guide me how to fix this gradle issues

```
PS C:\Users\yorky\Desktop\skype> flutter run
```

Using hardware rendering with device Android SDK built for x86. If you get graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with

```
--enable-software-rendering
```

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...

```
Initializing gradle... 1.3s

Resolving dependencies...

ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\yorky\Desktop\skype\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:

Build file 'C:\Users\yorky\Desktop\skype\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:

A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> ASCII

* Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

Command: C:\Users\yorky\Desktop\skype\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

Comment: is your project androidX enabled

Answer (score 0):

Flutter boilerplate [includes](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/40181) gradle distribution 5.6.2 and plugin version 3.5.0 as of [Flutter 1.12 (stable)](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/release-notes/release-notes-1.12.13) released last Dec 11 2019. I suggest using the latest version of Flutter as this uses the latest version which is also mentioned from [this comment](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37523#issuecomment-565661140) related to this issue.